# How to get the Response Headers from IHttpResponse

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I'd like to be able to retrieve the response headers for logging purposes, but do see a Headers property on the Interface, but I do see OriginalResponse. Are we supposed to cast this and use it? Will this contain any headers SS might have injected? My usage of this Interface is in a Global Filter defined as

```
ResponseFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, responseDto) =>
{
    // Log portions of the response i.e. Headers
});
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **httpReq.Headers** is exactly the same instance that you would get from an [ASP.NET HttpRequest.Headers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Extensions/HttpRequestWrapper.cs#L148) or self-hosting [HttpListenerRequest.Headers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Extensions/HttpListenerRequestWrapper.cs#L228).

So it's **exactly the same** as manually casting the underlying the request and accessing it directly, e.g:

#### HttpRequest Headers

For ASP.NET

```
var aspNetRequestHeaders = ((HttpRequest)httpReq.OriginalRequest).Headers;
```

For HttpListener:

```
var httpListenerHeaders = ((HttpListenerRequest)httpReq.OriginalRequest).Headers;
```

#### HttpResponse Headers

There is no Headers collection currently exposed on the [IHttpResponse](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IHttpResponse.cs) so you would need to use a similar approach to access them from the underlying HTTP Response object. Though you can easily wrap them in your own Extension method, e.g:

```
public static NameValueCollection GetHeaders(this IHttpResponse) 
{
  var aspNetResponseHeaders = httpReq.OriginalResponse as HttpResponse;
  return aspNetResponseHeaders != null 
     ? aspNetResponseHeaders.Headers
     : ((HttpListenerResponse)httpReq.OriginalResponse).Headers; //Http Listener
}
```

Comment: I should have articulated that I want the Response Headers

Comment: Cool, I've updated it to show how to access the response headers using a similar approach.

Comment: I'm sitting here trying out the code and SO is just updating REAL-TIME with your edits.. very cool.  Thanks Demis.."almost' done with my initial deep dive, all future SS projects will benefit from what I've learned over the past 2 weeks.  You're help and understanding are very much appreciated. Stephen

Comment: Brilliant, looking forward to seeing what you create! :)